# file extension query

Tags: file, text-files

I have a text file c1.data....Im trying to open it but it is not getting open up? what software do I need for it?

Comment: This question is for superuser if it really a proper question...

Comment: What kind of file is it?  If you rename it to a .txt file, can you open it up in notepad/wordpad?

Comment: i opened it in the notepad...It basically contains numbers. But in notepad, it is not coming in the correct format.

Comment: i can open it in the wordpad...thanks edward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing numbers, if they are somewhat organized, you might try importing the file in Excel.